# django-chartit highcharts options object "chart" not displaying subtitle

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I get different results in the displayed chart when I use the highcharts option "chart" in chart_options. Example 1 will display the subtitle but not the background color. Example 2 will show the background color but not the subtitle. Anyone else encountered this behavior?

Python v2.7.5
Django v1.10
django-chartit v0.2.7
django-highcharts v0.1.7

```
Example 1: displays subtitle, not backgroundColor
#Create the PivotChart object
site_prod_pivotcht = PivotChart(
  datasource = site_prod_ds,
    series_options = [
          {'options':{
              'type': 'column',
              'stacking': False},
            'terms': [
              'prod_value',
              'wx_adj_value']}
        ],
        chart_options =
            {'title': {
               'text': 'Actual versus Wx Adjusted Production Data'},
             'subtitle': {
               'text': report_range},
           'backgroundColor': '#7FFFD4',
           'xAxis': {
                'title': {
                   'text': 'Group:Sites'}}
        }

Example 2: displays backgroundColor, not subtitle
#Create the PivotChart object
site_prod_pivotcht = PivotChart(
  datasource = site_prod_ds,
    series_options = [
          {'options':{
              'type': 'column',
              'stacking': False},
            'terms': [
              'prod_value',
              'wx_adj_value']}
        ],
        chart_options =
            {'chart':{
             'title': {
               'text': 'Actual versus Wx Adjusted Production Data'},
             'subtitle': {
               'text': report_range},
           'backgroundColor': '#7FFFD4',
           'xAxis': {
                'title': {
                   'text': 'Group:Sites'}}}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more trial and error, I found the following works as intended.

```
chart_options =
    {'chart':{
        'backgroundColor': '#7FFFD4',
        'title': {
            'text': 'Actual versus Wx Adjusted Production Data'}},
     'subtitle': {
        'text': report_range},
     'credits': {
        'enabled': False},
     'xAxis': {
        'title': {
            'text': 'Group:Sites'}}
    }
```